# Lambda, get properties from nested list

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda

I'm trying to retrieve a list of UserProfile-objects of a given CustomerId. I Have theese pocos:

```
public class UserRole
    {

        [Key]
        [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int UserRoleId { get; set; }
        public Role Role { get; set; }
        public Customer Customer { get; set; }
        public virtual UserProfile UserProfile { get; set; }
    }

    public class Customer
    {
        public Customer()
        {
            this.UserRoles = new Collection<UserRole>();
        }
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int CustomerId { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Gruppens namn")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [InverseProperty("Customers")]
        public virtual ICollection<UserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
    }
```

I can't seem to find a way to actually get the UserProfiles. I can get a list of UserRoles by doing:

`dbContext.Customers.First(c => c.CustomerId == customer.CustomerId).UserRoles`

but cannot access UserProfiles of of that object. I also tried

`dbContext.UserRoles.Where(c => c.Customer.CustomerId == customerId)`

but same result. Ideas?

Comment: Well your custom has *multiple* roles - so talking about "the UserProfile" makes no sense. Which do you want?

Comment: `UserRoles` is a collection. It doesn't have a `UserProfile`

Comment: I want a list of ALL UserProfiles

Comment: dbContext.UserRoles.Select(ur => ur.UserProfile).ToList();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the list of profiles for a specific customer:

```
var result = dbContext.UserRoles
                   .Where(ur => ur.Customer.CustomerId == customer.CustomerId)
                   .Select(ur => ur.UserProfile);
```